# Micromax A57 is not displayed in Eclipse Device List

Tags: connection-issues, usb-debugging, micromax-a57

I have purchased a new Micromax A57 (Ninja-3) smart cell phone. I want to install my application from Eclipse directly, because i need to see the Logcat output for testing my Application.

I just installed the software which came with device and also downloaded the Drivers from this link [Micromax A57 Drivers](http://www.micromaxinfo.com/mobiles/feature-phones/bolt/A57-ninja-3)

But the problem is that the device is not listed in Eclipse.
I just read few articles which are telling me to root the device. But my phone is under warranty, so I don't want to root it at all, to not void its warranty.

Is there anything else I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your device has usb debugging enabled. what happens if you execute "adb devices"? Is it listed?

Comment: No, My device is not display in "adb devices", but when i enabled usb debugging it display in "Safely remove hardware and Eject Media"

Comment: You must enable usb debugging to see it in 'adb devices'. and probably you cant enable it, because your phone is connected via usb to your pc. remove it from the pc and enable it.

Comment: I do it so many times, but still my device is not listed in Eclipse.

Comment: Hey, today suddenly my friend Dhaval Pandya (Droider in Stackoverflow) doing something with my device and it is display in the Eclipse device list by enabling debugging mode , I thought the problem was in driver of Micromax, but it was not,  

    but its display Micromax A56 instead A57 in the Eclipse, i think this is Micromax Company's fault, Finnaly I can run my application from direct Eclipse to my device, Thanks to Dhaval and all of you...

Comment: Hi Jayesh, I am too having the same problem with Micromax A57. I googled a lot and even communicated with the micromax help desk too, still no luck, Could you please help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After a long search, finally I made my Micromax A57 to connect with eclipse and made it to suit for development.

1. Installed **Moborobo** (All in one Android smart phone management tool).
2. Perform `stop -server / start -server` using ADB.
3. Reboot the device.
4. Restart the eclipse.

Device got detected.(Eclipse - list of adb devices)

List of attached devices: [image: ADB list of devices]

Hope, this would be surely helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Nandagopal , thanks for your answer , from where I can get Moborobo tool ? Actually I don't know exactly what I have done last time , but my device is listed in only my PC where I worked, at that time my device wouldn't listed in another PC of my colleague and also in My Laptop, but now my device is not listed right now from last one week, I think its because of Android 4.4.2 sdk update

Comment: Today I install Moborobo , and as it install my device is display in eclipse device list without any process(reboot device or restart eclipse ), thanks Nandagopal, can I get this software for linux OS ?

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, I have **Micromax A-52**. It won't shows in eclipse on **Windows** & **Linux-Ubuntu** but **it is showing on Linux-Mint & Mac-machines**. I haven't tried on any others yet. So its might not the problem with your eclipse and system or even with device (*It can be manufacturer's fault*). I can just suggest you to try on more options if available.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution posible for using your phone for developing android apps is to root your phone.

This is a useful link for doing that:

[root you phone tutorial](http://androidforums.com/a57-all-things-root/617889-rooting-micromax-a57-ninja-3-just-5-min-updated.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer , but I don't want to root my cell phone at all , It will loose warranty of Device, let me know if any other way please...